# How to make Tensorflow GPU and keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip says that `# Anything above 2.10 is not supported on the GPU on Windows Native`
I am trying to use keras-cv, which requires tensorflow 2.11

Is there any way to make keras-cv work with tensorflow gpu?

I am using windows 11

Comment: It says not supported on Windows native, it is supported on WSL, and you did not mention which OS you are using at all.

Comment: I use windows 11

Comment: So use WSL, that is very clear from the tensorflow docs.

Comment: Hi @Orl13, Could you please try installing `keras_cv =<0.3.5` which will be compatible with `Tensorflow==2.10` and also install `protobuf 3.20` (`pip install protobuf==3.20` after installing all the packages which is compatible to every package. Let us if the issue still persists.